# Which missing library results in the message '/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0'?

Tags: ld, glibc, lazarus, freepascal, library-path

I am cross compiling a Lazarus program, creating a 32bit program on a 64bit Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr system, and everything apparently compiles to the very end when I get this messsage

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
```

What is the full name of the library whose absence results in this error mesage?

`libc6-dev:i386` appears to be the most likely library, but when I try to install it with apt indicates `build-essential g++ gcc gcc-multilib` will be removed so I abort it.

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-libc-dev linux-libc-dev:i386
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc:i386 manpages-dev:i386
Recommended packages:
  gcc:i386 c-compiler:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED
  build-essential g++ gcc gcc-multilib
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libc6-dev:i386 linux-libc-dev:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-libc-dev
1 to upgrade, 2 to newly install, 4 to remove and 18 not to upgrade.
Need to get 3,126 kB of archives.
After this operation, 12.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Comment: [common...](https://www.google.fr/search?client=opera&q=lglib-2.0&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was the `libglib2.0-0:i386` package. It was already installed earlier, but it had not been fully configured.

It was present in the `/lib/i386-linux` directory and I had to create a symlink to it include it to the `fpc.cfg` configuration file used by Free Pascal.

`locate  libglib | grep ^/lib` produced:

```
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4002.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4002.0
```

I symlinked it with the expected name:

```
ln -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so
```

then added to the Lazarus installations `fpc.cfg` file

```
#ifdef cpui386
 -Fl/usr/lib32
 -Fl/lib/i386-linux-gnu
#endif
```